# Qt Creator book

Tags: qt-creator

Is there any PDF tutorial or book how to Qt Creator and Developer ?

Comment: QtCreator has very nice built in reference, just press F1 ;)

Answer (score 6):

Qt Assistant, now embebbed in Qt Creator I believe, is very nice. IMHO, the greatest selling point of Qt is the quality of it's documentation.

But if you want a book [C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131872494) is *really* nice. It's not Qt Creator specific but you're not going to have trouble reading it.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pdf by paul and adam ezust.
first edition:
www.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~hughm/ap/books/CppQt4.pdf

second edition:

```
ftp://91.193.236.10/pub/docs/linux-support/programming/C%2B%2B/%5BPrentice%20Hall%5D%20-%20Introduction.to.Design.Patterns.in.CPP.with.Qt.2nd.Edition.pdf
```

I suggest the second edition, as the first one is not written very well